# How can I disable cache on a specific page only in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm running a job aggregator and I wish to avoid cache on my post feed, since its showing outdated results to my users. We're running on Next.JS.

I've searched through their docs, but didn't find a way about how to do it...

Does someone have an idea?

I assume its on next.config.js, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Do you find out the solution to this problem?

Comment: I thinks it's worth it to have a look at this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42991

Answer (score 12):

### Via next.config.js

Set the header `no-cache` on the path that you want.

```
module.exports = {
  headers: () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-store',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Docs: [NextJS Header Overriding Behavior](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#header-overriding-behavior)

Comment: This was very helpful. I didn't have to rewrite my code. Just added this config. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just a heads up, this should not work in production neither in the app router, nor in the pages router. According to next's documentation, you cannot set Cache-Control headers in next config for pages or assets, as those headers will be overwritten in production.
See, for pages router: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/headers#cache-control
See, for app router: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/headers#cache-control

Answer (score 3):

This seems work if server-side rendering

```
Page.getInitialProps = async ({ store, res }) => {
    if (res) {
        // res available only at server
        // no-store disable bfCache for any browser. So your HTML will not be cached
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
    }

    await store.dispatch(action());
    return {};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In server components while fetching data from an API:

```
async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://xyx.a.b",{
    cache:"no-cache"
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#fetchcache

layout.tsx | page.tsx | route.ts

```
export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store';
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only option that works with App Router

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, however it seems, disabling the ETag should do the trick.
Have you tried that!

`generateEtags: false,`

Read more on the same topic [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/disabling-etag-generation).
NBaua

Comment: But the question is "spesific page only"