# In next js, after building and deploying on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In next js, after building and deploying on the server, there is an error for those who have already opened the website, and it will not be fixed until the browser is cleared. What is the way to clear the cache from all browsers of old users?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257837/how-can-i-disable-cache-on-a-specific-page-only-in-next-js) help in any way?

Comment: what is the error ?