# Nextjs: Middleware does not run for all request when requests are repeat

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create an `nextjs` with `app` dir with multi language

[image]

the router sould be `/en/...` or `/vi/...`

To avoid use `useParams` to all component include `Link` component like this:

```
const {lang} = useParams()

return <>
  <Link href={`/${lang}/page`}>Page</Link>
</>
```

I create an `middleware.ts`:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  const getLangInPathname = pathname.split("/")[1];

  if (getLangInPathname !== "en" && getLangInPathname !== "vi") {
    let lang = request.cookies.get("_lang")?.value || "en";

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lang}${pathname}`, request.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
};
```

Now I just need: `<Link href='/page'>Page</Link>`. And the middleware will redirect to right router with `[lang]`.

The problem is:

[image]
[image]

When Im in dashboard, I routing between profile and dashboard some times. Current `[lang]` is `vi`.

Now I switch lang to `en` by use `<SwitchLang/>`:

```
"use client";

import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { useParams, usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function SwitchLang() {
  const { lang } = useParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    Cookies.set("_lang", lang);
  }, [lang]);

  const handleChangeLang = (lang: string) => {
    Cookies.set("_lang", lang);
    router.push(pathname.replace(pathname.slice(1, 3), lang));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onClick={() => handleChangeLang("en")}
        style={{
          fontSize: lang === "en" ? 25 : 14,
        }}
      >
        en
      </span>
      <br />
      <span
        onClick={() => handleChangeLang("vi")}
        style={{
          fontSize: lang === "vi" ? 25 : 14,
        }}
      >
        vi
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SwitchLang;
```

Then routing, the `[lang]` auto turn to `vi`. If I try to continue switch lang to `en`, the lang til turn to `vi` when I routing.

I create a [github](https://github.com/lequangkhanh2901/test-middleware-nextjs) for this case here.

And I checked in network tab of browser. the routing then seem not send request to server:
[image]

It only call `favicon.ico`, `middleware` not run on these request.

I aslo try to

```
module.exports = {
  headers: () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-store',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

in `next.config.js` to disable cache and hope it work but not. [How can I disable cache on a specific page only in Next.JS - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473159/18710252)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior by default as described in this [Github issue #30938.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30938#issuecomment-970239412)

> This is expected since we are caching HEAD requests to reduce the amount of requests as much as possible which can still be problematic [#30901](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30901)

However, you can stop caching HEAD requests and force their revalidation by setting the "x-middleware-cache" header with a "no-cache value", before redirecting in the middleware. (see related [PR #32767](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/32767))

```
...

  if (getLangInPathname !== "en" && getLangInPathname !== "vi") {
    let lang = request.cookies.get("_lang")?.value || "en";

    const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lang}${pathname}`, request.url));
 
    // SET MIDDLEWARE NO-CACHE HEADER
    response.headers.set('x-middleware-cache', 'no-cache');

    return response;
  }

...
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all... requests are still being cached

Comment: @k_krrs, did you find any solution / workaround?

Comment: @EnKratia from what I found the requests are cached only if the redirect code is 308 Permanent Redirect. When I set the code to 307 Temporary Redirect it works fine, but this is bad for SEO. So what I did was, check if the user agent is a bot with the Next 'isBot' function, if it is a bot, redirect with 308, if it is a real user redirect with 307. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: @k_krrs, thank you for answer. But status 307 means full page reload, right?(

Comment: @EnKratia yup... what's your use case? can you explain it a bit?